# Dynamics CRM SDK filter query on custom field

Tags: c#, linq, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to pull items from the salesorder entity into my WPF Application (C#)
I have created a custom field in the crm called new_xero and published. This is a two-option field. I have 4 orders, 2 with nothing set for this field, one with 'no' selected and one with 'yes' selected.

I have the following code:

```
QueryExpression qeLocations = new QueryExpression("salesorder");

        string[] cols = { "salesorderid", "name" };
        qeLocations.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(cols);


        var locations = this.OrgService.RetrieveMultiple(qeLocations);

        listBox1.ItemsSource = (from location in locations.Entities
                                where location.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_xero") == "false"
                                //where (bool)location["new_xero"] == false
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Name = location["name"],
                                        LocationID = location["salesorderid"]
                                    }).Take(5);
```

It seems that everything I try to do to the line `where location.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_xero") == "false"` I can't filter to only those where the option is set to 'no'
I have tried int filtering against 0, string against 'false', 'False', 'No', 'no' but can't seem to find the right solution.

Cheers

Comment: shouldn't locations.Entitles be locations.BusinessEntities?  also check what location.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_xero") actualy returns, you might find it is the dataType CrmBoolean, I've seen that happen a few times, althoug i usually avoid mixing var with CRMs services andstick to using the static types.

Comment: also did you remember to refresh your webservice referencec in visual studio to get the newley publlished attribute?

Comment: Hi Stuart, Thanks for your replies. I have added the following line `label1.Content = resp.Entity["new_xero"].GetType();` which outputs `system.boolean` to the label. BusinessEntities and CrmBoolean throw errors for no definition in 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection' and no type or namespace found.

Comment: Sorry, should have spotted you were using 2011 not 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, I needed to add the field new_xero to the cols array.
Then either `where location.GetAttributeValue<bool>("new_xero")` or `where location["new_xero"].ToString() == "False"` (although opposing for true and false!

Many thanks,
Chris